# ActionCable install causing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I'm trying to set up ActionCables with my rails 5 app, I've ran rails g channel Posts and now my server is reseting every couple of seconds with this error:

```
Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-09-16 11:16:12 +0100
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-09-16 11:16:12 +0100
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)

NotImplementedError (only partial hijack is supported.):

rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:74:in `block in service'
actioncable (5.0.0.1) lib/action_cable/connection/stream.rb:43:in `hijack_rack_socket'
actioncable (5.0.0.1) lib/action_cable/connection/client_socket.rb:57:in `start_driver'
actioncable (5.0.0.1) lib/action_cable/connection/client_socket.rb:68:in `rack_response'
actioncable (5.0.0.1) lib/action_cable/connection/web_socket.rb:32:in `rack_response'
actioncable (5.0.0.1) lib/action_cable/connection/base.rb:208:in `respond_to_successful_request'
actioncable (5.0.0.1) lib/action_cable/connection/base.rb:74:in `process'
actioncable (5.0.0.1) lib/action_cable/server/base.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:17:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:46:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:222:in `context'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:216:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:552:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:86:in `service'
/home/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
/home/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
/home/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:296:in `block in start_thread'
  Rendering /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (3.1ms)
  Rendering /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendering /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (24.7ms)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Accessing mime types via constants is deprecated. Please change `Mime::HTML` to `Mime[:html]`. (called from const_missing at /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:52)
  Rendering /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb
  Rendered /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendering /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript
  Rendering /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string
  Rendered /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendering /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string
  Rendered /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendering /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string
  Rendered /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Accessing mime types via constants is deprecated. Please change `Mime::WEB_CONSOLE_V2` to `Mime[:web_console_v2]`. (called from const_missing at /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:52)
  Rendered /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (25.3ms)
  Rendering /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript
  Rendered /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.3ms)
  Rendering /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript
  Rendered /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.4ms)
  Rendered /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (46.4ms)
[2016-09-16 11:16:13] ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer @ io_fillbuf - fd:11 
    /home/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:82:in `eof?'
    /home/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:82:in `run'
    /home/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:296:in `block in start_thread'
```

I'm pretty new to rails so I'm not really sure what is going on, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: which application server you were using in development mode ?

Answer (score 3):

try to add gem 'puma' to the group :development of the Gemfile