# ActionCable never establishes connection to channel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, real-time, puma, actioncable

I am trying to get a first ActionCable example running, however, I feel like there is never a connection from client to channel established. I have pretty much followed the [edge guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html) on everything else not mentioned here.

```ruby
# app/channels/notifications_channel.rb
class NotificationsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    byebug
    stream_from "notifications"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    stop_all_streams
  end

  def receive(data)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast("notifications", data)
  end
end
```

byebug never has been called. I actually can put in a bunch of syntax gibberish into that file and will not see an error anywhere. It's like the file is never loaded.

Here is the javascript though, and I would expect to see a "connected" alert if it would establish a connection, which never happens. The file is loaded and executed properly though, as I can inspect the `App` variable in my browser console and it will show me the `App.notifications` as a valid Subscription object (it doesn't help much debugging though as most properties are functions).

```js
// app/assets/javascripts/channels/notifications.js
App.notifications = App.cable.subscriptions.create("NotificationsChannel", {
  connected: function() {
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
    alert('connected');
  },

  disconnected: function() {
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  },

  received: function(data) {
    alert(data)
    // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
    $("#notifications").prepend(data.html);
  }
});
```

If it helps any further, my Puma always starts in "Single mode", where I am not sure if this might be the issue nor how to fix it.

Comment: Installing puma gem worked with me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42405410/1770571

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is the reason. I somehow just tried to set everything to default and see if it's gonna work, and it did. I then by slowly adding configs and code back figured out what actually was the issue, which was the following line in the `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
config.reload_classes_only_on_change = false
```

Setting this to `true` solved it.

Comment: Thanks! I had the same issue and changing to `reload_classes_only_on_change` it solved!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and set `config.reload_classes_only_on_change` does not help.

I need to wrap channel code by `turbolinks:load`

```js
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
   // ...
   const channel = consumer.subscriptions.create(
     { channel: channel_name, ...other params },
     connected() {}, 
     disconnected() {}
   )
})
```